# Public IP address on url

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012, ip, url-routing

I successfully setup DNS and a web server with all the requirements. Everything is getting resolved properly such as domain names and reverse proxies.

My question is, how can I set the public IP being on url like this: [server default page?](http://204.232.232.211/).

The main server is behind a firewall router and is Windows based. It is in a dedicated hosting environment.

Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you want an IP address in a URL, just do it. No setup is required, assuming your server is set up to listen on that IP address and will accept requests without a Host header.

Comment: The server in question yes is listen on my public ip address and accept requests based on header names, so I host 4-5 websites. The thing I want to accomplish is this: if by any curiosity somebody type my  public ip address into url address bar I would like to show a simple default page as shown on the link I posted.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what web server you're using.

Comment: @cadobe Configure that host the same way you configured all the others.

Comment: I have tried but for some reason I am getting 404, I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a site to IIS with a catch-all binding, meaning all assigned IP addresses and no host name.

If all your other sites have host name bindings, this new site will handle all requests coming into the server that don't have one of those bound host names, including all requests with IP addresses.

On the new site, set up a single page acting as the server default page. Set the default document and the 404 error page to the same page.

Comment: Thanks to Peter Hahndorf my question/issue is solved. Simple and elegant. Thanks again. I wish to vote up your solution but seems to be I do not have enough credentials.

Comment: You should be able to mark it as a correct answer.